# What controller is the one included in this picture?

Tags: game-controllers

I can't make out the writing on the controller because of the picture's quality. Can anyone identify what brand and model this is?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android TV controller... There are many similar ones on Amazon but I believe this one is discontinued already.

http://www.businessinsider.com/android-tv-game-controller-2014-6

Comment: Oh okay, thanks! Sucks that it's discontinued.